# Can a Snowflake function return results from a query?

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is a Snowflake function able to return a query's results?

In my particular case I'm trying to save data from a table into an array within the function so I can run a series of checks.

```
create or replace function GeoLocator ("STRING" VARCHAR(16777216) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$

//This function will find the location of a transaction.


//PATTERN 1 ARRAY -- THESE WILL BE THE MOST COMMON LOCATIONS
var pattern_1_most_common = [];

 //Location Data
var rs_pattern_1_sql =  snowflake.execute( { sqlText:
`
 SELECT LOCATION
 FROM A_TABLE_THAT_HAS_ALL_LOCATIONS
 WHERE "STATE" = 'California'

`} );

//Load location pattern values into Pattern 1 Array i.e. "San Francisco, CA","Walnut Creek, CA", etc...
while (rs_pattern_1_sql.next()) {
       pattern_1_most_common.push(rs_pattern_1_sql.getColumnValue(1))
    };


// THERE WILL BE LOGIC HERE TO LOOP THROUGH ALL THE LOCATIONS AND CHECK IF THERE IS A MATCH

// FOR NOW, FOR BREVITY LETS JUST RETURN PATTERN_1_MOST_COMMON 

return pattern_1_most_common
$$
```

But when I run

`select GEOLOCATOR('text here')` I get the following error:

```
JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: snowflake is not defined in GEOLOCATOR at 'var rs_pattern_1_sql = snowflake.execute( { sqlText:' position 24 stackstrace:
```

------------------------- Update

Concretely, I'm trying to take the following code which is currently a procedure, because I was not able to load data from a table into a function using something like `snowflake.execute`.

```js
create or replace procedure GeoLocator ("STRING_PARAM" VARCHAR(16777216) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$

//This function will find the location of a transaction.

//Creating STRING_PASS_THRU so that we can pass the functions parameter into a Javascript variable
var STRING_PARAM_PASS_THRU_SQL = snowflake.execute( {  sqlText: ` select '${STRING_PARAM}' as letsgo ` } );
var STRING_PARAM_PASS_THRU_LIST = []

while (STRING_PARAM_PASS_THRU_SQL.next()) {
       STRING_PARAM_PASS_THRU_LIST.push(STRING_PARAM_PASS_THRU_SQL.getColumnValue(1))
    };


//PATTERN 1 ARRAY -- THESE WILL BE THE MOST COMMON LOCATIONS
var pattern_1_most_common = [];

 //Location Data --- ** This is what I cant figure out how to do in a Snowflake function. **
var rs_pattern_1_sql =  snowflake.execute( { sqlText:

`
SELECT 'San Francisco' as LOCATION
UNION 
SELECT 'Oakland' as LOCATION

`} );

//Load location pattern values into Pattern 1 Array i.e. "San Francisco, CA","Walnut Creek, CA", etc...
while (rs_pattern_1_sql.next()) {
       pattern_1_most_common.push(rs_pattern_1_sql.getColumnValue(1))
    };


//Loop through locations see if theres a match
for (var i=0; i<pattern_1_most_common.length; i++) {

    if (STRING_PARAM_PASS_THRU_LIST[0].match(pattern_1_most_common[i]) !== null){
       return STRING_PARAM_PASS_THRU_LIST[0].match(pattern_1_most_common[i]);
    }
    else {
     continue;


    }  ;


                                                      };

$$;
```

So running the above procedure

`CALL GeoLocator('Snowflake - Downtown Oakland')` would yield `'Oakland'`

However I cannot do something like

```sql
Select 
call geolocator(COLUMN_NAMEHERE) as Location
from TABLE
```

And this is why I'm trying to convert the geolocator to a function rather than a procedure, but it seems as though (and i might be wrong here) Snowflake functions are missing a lot of functionality...such as loading data from a table using `snowflake.execute` into a variable so I can loop through that said variable.

Comment: Hey Mike,

Are you using the APIs in the right place?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html

Comment: I believe so...the documentation provided is somewhat lengthy to infer what in particular you're referencing.   This function I'm attempting to create will run regex operations, similar to REGEXP_SUBSTR , but will go through a series of values to attempt to match on.

Comment: To Patrick's point, the "snowflake" JavaScript API is for stored procedures and is not available in JavaScript UDFs. If you can get all the data you need passed in through the columns one row at a time to process your logic loop, you can use a Javascript UDTF for this: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-tabular-functions.html.

Comment: I meant the use of the API, it relates to Stored Procs.

We can return content in functions too, either as scalar or table udfs

Comment: @GregPavlik  Thank you for the response, apologies that I'm still confused. I looked at the Tabular JavaScript UDFs (UDTFs) link, but I need the function to return a 'varchar' not a table. I updated my question with the exact code I'm trying to recreate out of a function.  Appreciate the guidance.

Comment: @patrick_at_snowflake thank you Patrick, I realize functions can return data, but how can it execute queries within itself? I updated my question above hopefully providing a little more color...

Comment: @mikelowry, your comment in the stored procedure: `** This is what I cant figure out how to do in a Snowflake function. **`. The "snowflake" object is available in JavaScript stored procedures and it not available in JavaScript UDFs. You can't run "snowflake.execute" in a JavaScript UDF because the "snowflake" object that runs the execute method is not included in the UDF environment for JavaScript. There's no way to run a SQL statement in a JavaScript UDF, only pass in variables. If you use a UDTF, the variables passed in can be the values of the columns for each row.

Comment: Got it, thank you @GregPavlik